# Creating custom JavaScript object from data returned by jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create a custom javascript object which contains data returned from a jQuery AJAX request, but I don't know which is the right way to do it. I was thinking maybe one way could be to include the AJAX request inside the constructor function so the object is created like this:

```
// Constructor function
function CustomObject(dataUrl) {
    var that = this;

    $.ajax(dataUrl, {
        success: function (json) {
            that.data = $.parseJSON(json);
        }
    });
}

// Creating new custom object
var myObject = new CustomObject('http://.....');
```

Another way may be to use a function which does the AJAX and then returns the new object based on the data from the AJAX response.

```
function customObject(dataUrl) {
    // Constructor function
    function CustomObject(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    $.ajax(dataUrl, {
        success: function (json) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(json);
            return new CustomObject(data);
        }
    });
}

// Creating new custom object
var myObject = customObject('http://.....')
```

I would like to know what is the best practice when doing something like this, as well as advantages/disadvatages of different methods. Maybe you can point me to some article or example on something similiar to what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want an object to be created? Also, reading this 3-part series has helped me think differently in JavaScript - http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/

Comment: What about returning a JSON from server-side with the object structure and data you already want?

Comment: I am creating an object because it has custom methods

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be a better approach, it makes your `CustomObject` only knowledgeable about the data it contains. Here you delegate the work of creating objects to a factory, and pass in a callback to get a reference to the created object, since ajax is asynchronous. If you don't mind making it synchronous, then the `createCustomObject` function can just return the instance, and the callback can be removed.

```
function CustomObject(data) {
    this.data = data;
}

var factory = (function(){
   function create(dataUrl, objectClass, callback){
       $.ajax({
           url: dataUrl,
           success: function (data) {
              callback(new objectClass(data));
            }
           });
   }
   return{
      createCustomObject: function(dataUrl, callback){
          create(dataUrl, CustomObject, callback);
      }
   };
})();

// Creating new custom object
var myObject = null;
factory.createCustomObject('http://..', function(customObject){
   myObject = customObject;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that the second method is better because then you only create a new `CustomObject` once the script is actually fully prepared to do so (i.e. it has the data it needs from the AJAX request).